# How to customize highlighted data point circles in Flex charts?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, customization

I need to customize a look and feel of standard Flex LineChart with LineSeries. I cannot figure out how to change default circles drawn when the mouse pointer is over a data point.

[image: How to change UI element pointed by the red arrow?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It is necessary to create a custom `itemRenderer` and draw whatever you want in the `MOUSE_OVER` event handler. Chart's `showDataTipTargets` property has to be set to `false`

While looking for a solution, I forgot that `itemRenderer` is the Flex component and can handle mouse events. My colleagues pointed to it and helped resolve the issue.

**Code**

CustomDataTipTargetRenderer.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                creationComplete="init()"
                ...>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void
            {
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver); 
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
            }

            private function onMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
            { 
                // Show custom data tip target point. 
            } 

            private function onMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
            { 
                // Hide custom data tip target point.
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

YourView.mxml

```
<mx:LineChart ...
              showDataTips="true"
              showDataTipTargets="false">
    ...
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries ... itemRenderer="yournamespace.CustomDataTipTargetRenderer">
            ...
        </mx:LineSeries>
    </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove those circles, set property `showDataTipTargets` of chart to `false`. If you want to customize them, you can:

1. Create your custom `dataTipRenderer` and perform skinning and drawing there.
   **OR**
2. Extend your `LineChart` and override `positionAllDataTips` method, which is defined in `ChartBase` class. Here's the code, responsible for drawing the circles:

Code:

```
if (showTarget) {

    if (len>1) {
        if (calloutStroke) {
            calloutStroke.apply(g, null, null);
            if (tipData.isRight) {
                g.moveTo(localPts.x,
                    localPts.y+tipData.height/2);
            g.lineTo(tipData.x,
                    localPts.y+tipData.height/2);
            g.lineTo(tipData.x, tipData.y);
        }
        else {
            if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.RTL) {
                g.moveTo(localPts.x-tipData.width,
                        localPts.y+tipData.height/2);
            }
            else {
                g.moveTo(localPts.x+tipData.width,
                        localPts.y+tipData.height/2);
            }
            g.lineTo(tipData.x,
                    localPts.y+tipData.height/2);
            g.lineTo(tipData.x, tipData.y);
        }
    }
}

var tipColor:uint=tipData.hd.contextColor;
g.lineStyle(1, tipColor, 100);
g.moveTo(tipData.x, tipData.y);
g.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
g.drawCircle(tipData.x, tipData.y, TOOLTIP_TARGET_RADIUS);
g.endFill();
```

Comment: 1. you wrote: "set property showDataTipTargets of chart to false", but it is not what I need. The showDataTipTargets displays dots in the data points. The dot I pointed out appears when you move the cursor over one of data points.

Comment: 2. "custom dataTipRenderer" does not allow me to draw the circle point I specified on the image above. I tried to duplicate the functionality of CircleItemRenderer class and compleately removed the funcationality responsible for drawing any elements - still I could see the circle with dot when I moved the mouse over.

Comment: 3. "Extend your LineChart and override positionAllDataTips method, which is defined in ChartBase class" - only this one can help, but I have to figure out how to rewrite that giant positionAllDataTips method...

Comment: I gave up to override functionality of drawing different data points. The code above, provided by Timofei, is duplicated (!) in two places: ChartBase.positionDataTips and ChartBase.positionAllDataTips methods. Each method is about 350 lines of code and use some private variables initialized and populated in different places of the control! In order to override drawing of the circles, one has to almost duplicate about 1000 lines of code from the base control ((

My conclusion is the ChartBase is awful for customization of such element.

Anyway I thank Timofei for the help.

Comment: @timofei-davydik As Safor has mentioned, there's a ton of code to replicate here when overriding this method. Do you have the full code of your override to reference? How did you get past the references to things like _allTipCache?

Answer (score 1):

Timofei Davydik gave a very good answer, and it helped my work with datatips also

However I see in the comments that there was some confusion about how exactly to work with overriding the two massive functions, `ChartBase.positionDataTips` and `ChartBase.positionAllDataTips`.

A way to do this would be to do the following:

1. Create a new chart class that extends ChartBase or a child of that.
2. Set the ChartBase style, `showDataTipTargets`, to false.
3. Create a new Style, `showCustomDataTipTargets`, on your custom chart class.
4. Override `positionDataTips` and `positionAllDatatips`

The new overridden functions should look something like this:

```
override protected function positionDataTips():void
{
  this.setStyle("showDataTipTargets", false);

  // this will do all the normal rendering of the datatips and callout
  // but it will not draw the dataTipTarget because that is dependent upon
  // the style, showDataTipTargets
  super.positionDataTips();

  // now here you draw your custom datatip target. 
  // Use the following code as a guide, it is
  // copied from the ChartBase.positionDataTips
  /*
  if (len > 1)
  {
    if (calloutStroke)
    {
      calloutStroke.apply(g,null,null);

      if (tipData.isRight)
      {                   
        g.moveTo(chartLocalPts.x,
                chartLocalPts.y + tipData.height /  2);
        g.lineTo(tipData.x,
                chartLocalPts.y + tipData.height / 2);
        g.lineTo(tipData.x, tipData.y);
      }
      else
      {
        if(layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.RTL)
        {
        g.moveTo(chartLocalPts.x - tipData.width,
        chartLocalPts.y + tipData.height / 2);
        }
        else
        {
        g.moveTo(chartLocalPts.x + tipData.width,
        chartLocalPts.y + tipData.height / 2);
        }
          g.lineTo(tipData.x,
                  chartLocalPts.y + tipData.height / 2);
          g.lineTo(tipData.x, tipData.y);
        }
    }
  }

  var tipColor:uint = tipData.hd.contextColor;
  g.lineStyle(1, tipColor, 100);
  g.moveTo(tipData.x, tipData.y);
  g.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
  g.drawCircle(tipData.x, tipData.y, TOOLTIP_TARGET_RADIUS);
  g.endFill();

  g.beginFill(tipColor, 1);
  g.drawCircle(tipData.x, tipData.y,
            TOOLTIP_TARGET_INNER_RADIUS);
  g.endFill();
  */

}
```