# How do DataTips work in Flex charting?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, flex4, flex3, flex-charting

DataTips in Flex charting are a poorly documented and little-understood feature.

There are three parts:

- the DataTip, by default a box with text inside
- the DataTipTarget, by default a bulls-eye circle over the series' point
- the Callout, the line from dataTipTarget to the DataTip box

How are these three elements created/drawn and how can they be customized?

---

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263474/892191) on how to properly customize the rendering of the DataTipTargets and the Callout lines.

Comment: This will be a good post if you answer it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the `dataTipRenderer` style from the `ChartBase` class defaults to [`DataTip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/DataTip.html).

`DataTip` is an `IDataRenderer` and therefore can act as a renderer.
However, the method `DataTip.updateDisplayList(w,h)` does not draw the circle at the data point. It draws a rectangle with HTML-able text inside.

So what, then, draws the elusive bulls-eyes?

---

Now I did some digging, some Very Deep digging, and I have found the answers. I will document them here for others.

My SDK version is **4.1.0**.

The code that renders the circle data point upon hover, which is the default, is not a renderer as we thought, but in fact a function within the `mx.charts.chartClasses.ChartBase` class, line 3873:

```
/**
 *  Defines the locations of DataTip objects on the chart.
 *  This method ensures that DataTip objects do not overlap each other
 *  (if multiple DataTip objects are visible) or overlap their target data items.
 *  
 *  @langversion 3.0
 *  @playerversion Flash 9
 *  @playerversion AIR 1.1
 *  @productversion Flex 3
 */
protected function positionDataTips():void
```

There's a similar function `positionAllDataTips()` in the same class.

There is a simple boolean style on `ChartBase`, `showDataTipTargets`, that when set to false will disable the drawing of the circle on the line when hovering.

The datatip targets are rendered within the `positionDataTips()` function of `ChartBase` (starting at line 4204).

Once I figured out that `showDataTipTargets` is related to this, I was able to [answer another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263474/892191). There you can find a detailed explanation of how to customize the `DataTipTarget`

The `ChartBase` boolean property, `showDataTips`, toggles the rendering of datatip BOXES only. They are rendered using the style `dataTipRenderer`, and the text of the datatip box is created using property `dataTipFunction`.

---

To summarize, DataTips on charts can be understood as the following:

- `ChartBase.getStyle("showDataTipTargets"):Boolean` will toggle the visibility of the default circle that is rendered upon hovering over a point.

  - In order to actually make changes to the rendering of the DataTip Targets, you must override/modify the way they are drawn in `ChartBase.positionDataTips()` function
- The DataTip boxes are handled separately

  - `ChartBase.showDataTips:Boolean` will toggle the visibility of DataTips and DataTipTargets for the entire chart
  - `ChartBase.getStyle("dataTipRenderer"):Class` will handle the graphical rendering of the DataTip box only.
  - The `dataTipRenderer` will use the string returned by `ChartBase.dataTipFunction:Function` to display the data.
  - The convention that should be followed is:

    - A custom `dataTipRenderer` should handle the graphics/drawing of a DataTip
    - A custom `dataTipFunction` should handle the formatting of the text of the data for a given point
- The callout line, which is the optional line drawn from DataTipTarget to DataTip box, can be enabled and customized by setting `ChartBase.getStyle(“dataTipCalloutStroke”):IStroke`.